# Nativescript Array of Switch elements | Tricks to read value in tap of Button

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Scenario:

Using Nativescript 5.0 with Angular

1. I have data coming from API (customers.component.ts)
2. Rendering n number of  as many IDs I get from API. Works great (customers.component.html)
3. User taps the Switches to make his choice and finally taps Save Button which calls a function saveData()
4. In saveData(), I am unable to read which Switches are checked.

I tried below in customers.component.html, it renders perfectly based on the data received from API. No error in this.

```
<ListView [items]="_coursesmeta" [height]  = "_coursesmeta.length == 0 ? 30 : _coursesmeta.length * 70" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-result="item">   
        <GridLayout rows="auto auto" columns="* *" class="m-5" verticalAlignment="stretch">
            <Label class="h3 m-15" [text]="result.coursename" textWrap="true" row="0" col="0"></Label>
            <Switch [id]="'switch[' + id + ']'" class="m-15" row="0" col="1" ></Switch>                
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Is
[id]="'switch[' + id + ']'"
this ok?
Is there any way to read if any of the Switches are checked.

Switches are dynamically created based on API data.

**Edit - adding code below **

```
<ListView [items]="_coursesmeta" [height]  = "_coursesmeta.length == 0 ? 30 : _coursesmeta.length * 70" class="list-group">
          <ng-template let-result="item">   
          <GridLayout rows="auto auto" columns="* *" class="m-5" verticalAlignment="stretch">
          <Label class="h3 m-15" [text]="result.coursename" textWrap="true" row="0" col="0"></Label>
         <Switch [checked]="result.selected" class="m-15" row="0" col="1" ></Switch>               </GridLayout>
     </ng-template>
    </ListView>
```

and important portion of ts file is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

import { ObservableArray } from "data/observable-array";
import * as Permissions from "nativescript-permissions";
import { Coursemeta } from "../../shared/coursemeta.model";
import { CoursemetaService } from "~/app/shared/coursemeta.service";
var contacts = require( "nativescript-contacts" );

import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ContactManagerComponent implements OnInit {

    public constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private route: ActivatedRoute, private _coursemetaservice: CoursemetaService) { }
    public _coursesmeta: ObservableArray<Coursemeta> = new ObservableArray<Coursemeta>([]); 

    ngOnInit(): void {                 
        this.callerName=this.route.snapshot.params["callerName"]; 
        this.callerNumber=this.route.snapshot.params["callerNumber"]; 
        this.input="";
        this._coursemetaservice.getCoursesmeta()
            .pipe(finalize(() => this._isLoading = false))
            .subscribe((coursesmeta: Array<Coursemeta>) => {
                this._coursesmeta = new ObservableArray(coursesmeta);       
                this.courseCount=this._coursesmeta.length;        
                this._isLoading = false;                 
            });        
    }

public ShowSelectedCourses()
{

    for(var i=0; i < this._coursesmeta.length; i++)
    {
        if(this._coursesmeta.getItem(i).selected == false)
        {
            alert("false = " + i);
        }    
    }
    alert("Saved ....");        
}
}
```

What I expect is, if user slides the switch, then selected property should change its value as its part of observablearray.

**I am able to see data as expected, no error in API data communication, rendering is perfect.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutiple ways to achive the desired

1. Add the onSwitchChecked

and in your .ts file handle the onSwitchChecked

```
    import { Switch } from 'ui/switch';
    public onSwitchChecked(args) {
            const sortSwitch = <Switch>args.object;
            if (sortSwitch.id === 'id of your swich') {
                if (sortSwitch.checked) {
// Change the _coursesmeta or result.selected here.
    }
    }
```

2. Use the ng model for your result.checked e.g.

   ```
   <Switch [(ngModel)]='isSwitchChecked' (checkedChange)="onSwitchChecked($event)"></Switch>
   ```

and in yout .ts

```
 public onSwitchChecked() {
            alert(this.isSwitchChecked);
        }
```

I have created playground and you can test functionality [there](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=giJgV5).

Comment: Thanks Narendra for the help. My assumption of Observable Array was a two way automatic binding. i.e. Data from API will get bind to Switch state in .html and vice versa user changes of switch slide will automatically reflect into result.selected value of observable array. 

There is documentation for two way data binding, then why do we need to manually check id of switch that is pressed and then modify the result.selected? 

Though, meantime will try your solution Narendra.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using dynamic IDs. Also when using ListView, it's not guaranteed that all your Switches / templates are alive, as you scroll up and down same element will be recycled with different data to retain performance.

So you should play with data here, bind the checked state of Switch to a property in data item. For example

```
<Switch [checked]="result.selected" class="m-15" row="0" col="1" ></Switch>
```

Now you will just have to loop through the array to find which item is selected.

Comment: API provides dynamic data e.g. course id & course name
Will your code create Switch dynamically?
I have used dynamic IDs several thousands of times in web development, but not sure how it goes here in NS?

Comment: Listview takes an array of data items as input and renders items for each based on the item template you pass in. My code was just psuedo to showcase how you bind the checked property directly instead of I'd. Read more about ListView in the official docs.

Comment: Manoj, thanks for the correct input. I took a while to understand your suggestion. Now I am able to do it but console.log does not reflect user updated state of Switch.  Even when all Switches are slide to off state, console says true. As long as I feel, I am not doing anything wrong in ObservableArray. Any further clue will help me call it a day !!!